# mysql query help - need to take the load off PHP on duplicate checker script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that uploads a CSV and inserts into the database in a duplicate checker temp table.  At that point it does the following:

1) Checks itself (the temp table) for duplicates, deletes them all from temp table
2) Checks the customer table for duplicates, deletes them from temp table

Right now I'm doing this with php loops which seems to be dragging the whole thing to a grinding halt because the customer table has hundreds of thousands of records.  I believe that if I can put a lot of this into a query instead it might make things work better.  The upload works fine, here is the section of code in question.

```
<?
// look for duplicate account_no in the temp table
$sql_1 = "SELECT account_no,count(*) FROM tempTable GROUP BY account_no";
$result_1 = mysql_query($sql_1) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
while(list($acct,$numcount) = mysql_fetch_row($result_1)) {
// if there is a duplicate in tempTable, delete them all
 if($numcount>1) {
   $toBeRemoved+=$numcount;
   $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE(account_no = '$acct')";
   $result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
 }
}

// look for duplicate account_no in the customersTable and delete from tempTable
$sql_2 = "SELECT account_no FROM customersTable";
$result_2 = mysql_query($sql_2) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
while(list($acct) = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)) {
   $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE(account_no = '$acct')";
   $result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this all in prep of inserting the non-dups into the customers table?

Comment: Yes it is.  Which also goes smoothly

Comment: I would consider Kolink's answer and rewrite your process to skip the above code entirely and use INSERT IGNORE. It would get rid of the time consuming loops and perform the same process by ignoring the duplicates on insert.

Comment: Can't do this because the insert happens later and is controlled by the client user who is doing the inserting.  Not that it matters but by means of background, after the above steps the client user downloads a new CSV and reviews it before electing to insert them into the customer table.  The main thing is I need to get the second step (checking for dupes in the customer table and deleting from temp table) into a query if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the proper `UNIQUE` keys on the database tables, you can just blindly `INSERT` them using `INSERT IGNORE`, as this will ignore duplicate key errors and continue inserting the non-duplicate rows.

Comment: For reasons beyond my control, there is no unique key unless you consider account_no as the unique.  Also it does not do the insert until a few steps later, which is in a different process controlled by the user. The most important step here that is hanging the whole thing is the part about checking for duplicates in the customer table and deleting.  Is there any way to do this in a query?

Answer (score 1):

For the first table, you will need a column with a unique id:

```
DELETE FROM tempTable
USING tempTable, tempTable t2
WHERE tempTable.account_no = t2.account_no
   AND tempTable.id > t2.id
```

2nd table:

```
DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE account_no IN (SELECT account_no FROM customersTable)
```

You may also want to check that the index exists and is being used.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a better solution and I implemented it. However, it's still getting hung up on the second query.  Can you think of any solution at all that might prevent the hanging? Or perhaps a way to do this in batches and perhaps show the progress?

Comment: You can also try following syntax, it usually works much faster on large join tables: DELETE FROM tempTable
USING tempTable, customersTable ct
WHERE tempTable.account_no=ct.account_no

Comment: Thanks I tried it.  Still hangs forever.  There has got to be a way to go check 300k records without all this struggle.  Maybe a way to break it up?  I have no idea.  But I know 300k is not THAT much in the mysql world.

Comment: You might try adding an index to both tables on the account_no field, but I don't think that will help much because your sub-query is looking at every row in that table anyway.  I would try something like the query in my next comment for your second query.

Comment: DELETE FROM tempTable
USING tempTable, customersTable t2
WHERE tempTable.account_no = t2.account_no

Answer (score 0):

The final solution to this was to create an index on `account_no` and use a `JOIN`. Now it does everything in seconds. Thanks everyone for all your help!